# How can i join a table with another, then count not empty columns and group them by two other fields?

Tags: join, count, google-bigquery, union-all

(I have some issues adding the tables, as they are viewed as code. Have added the tags as code to include it)

I have a table with many columns (in example only a few)

| month | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021.06 |  | 87 | 987 | 987 | 87 |
| 2021.06 |  | 86 |  | 09 | 65 |
| 2021.06 |  |  |  | 09 | 65 |
| 2021.06 |  |  |  | 09 |  |
| 2021.05 | 85 |  |  | 09 | 65 |
| 2021.05 | 85 |  |  | 09 |  |
| 2021.05 | 87 |  |  | 09 |  |

I also have a second table with additional information connected to the id-number in the above table:

| id | branch | info1 | info2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 85 | branch1 | test4 | test5 |
| 86 | branch1 | test3 |  |
| 87 | branch2 | test2 |  |
| 987 |  | test1 |  |
| 09 | branch3 | test1 |  |
| 65 | branch1 | test1 |  |

I need to find a simple way of joining the information, count the number of not empty columns and group it by the month and the branch. The result should look like this

| month | branch | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021.05 | branch1 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2021.05 | branch2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021.05 | branch3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 |
| 2021.06 | branch1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| 2021.06 | branch2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2021.06 | branch3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 |
| 2021.06 |  | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

I have tried with join and union all, but the query is getting extremely large.

Comment: you forgot to show input data :o)

Comment: For some reason the tables cannot be added. Error say it is code but it isn't. Added it as code now

Comment: Added it correctly now. Found out I needed to add a space into empty cells in table for them not to be considered code :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select * from (
  select month, branch, id, col
  from table1 
  unpivot (id for col in (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5))
  left join table2 using(id)
)
pivot (count(id) for col in ('col1','col2','col3','col4','col5'))
# order by month, branch nulls last
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]